# create a dynamic php/html table with mysql specific value in <td> ("League"-System)

Tags: php, mysql

i struggle with the following structure / logic...
the project is about how to build a league on php & mysql
every player has to play against each other

i want to generate a (dynamic) table like this one:

```
<table border="1">

    <tr>
        <td>--</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>--</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>--</td>
        <td>--</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>--</td>
        <td>--</td>
        <td>--</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>--</td>
        <td>--</td>
        <td>--</td>
        <td>--</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>x</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>--</td>
        <td>--</td>
        <td>--</td>
        <td>--</td>
        <td>--</td>
        <td>x</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>--</td>
        <td>--</td>
        <td>--</td>
        <td>--</td>
        <td>--</td>
        <td>--</td>
    </tr>


</table>
```

Each number is a nickname, so this ends up how to display the stats

And now my stuff so far:

```
    $get_player = mysql_query("SELECT nickname, id FROM player");

$get_player_score = mysql_query("select 
    player_id, game1, game2, game3
from
    1on1_matches_scores
where
    1on1_matches_id = (select 
            id
        from
            1on1_matches
        where
            league_id = (select 
                    id
                from
                    league
                where
                    league_type_id = (select 
                            id
                        from
                            league_type
                        where
                            id = 1)
                        and season_id = (select 
                            id
                        from
                            season
                        where
                            id = 1))
        limit 1)");



while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($get_player))
    $results[$row[nickname]][] = $row[id];

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($get_player_score))
    $data[$row[player_id]][] = $row[game3];



echo "<table border='1'><tr>";
echo "<td>--</td>";


foreach ($results as $key => $value)
    echo "<td>$key</td>";
echo "</tr>";


foreach ($results as $key => $value) {
    echo "<tr><td>$key</td>";
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) :
        foreach ($value as $cell_value)
            echo "<td>Punkte: $cell_value</td>";
        endforeach;

    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Alright, how do i get a specific value (the result of a match) into the exact td from player 1 and player 2?

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't try to force it all into one big query. It would be interesting to see the full schema. I think you are having an issue with your tables. Maybe that makes it hard to wrap your mind around the actual problem. I'd do it as follows: fetch all player details for the league and cache them (in a var), fetch all games with results in that season, sort them by date, iterate and display results w/ player info per line. More info on how a league is calculated: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament